# CSS/HTML Modal- Using the Escape key/Click outside to close

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have the following modal working,

http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/

on my site. It's exactly what I want in terms of ease of use, and function. The only issue I have is how to make the modal close when the user either A) Clicks outside the modal window, or B) Hits the Escape key.

Any suggestions?

```
    <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                <h2>Modal Box</h2>

            <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
            <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For this you will need a little javascript. Check the code with some comments.

```
function modalClose() {
    if (location.hash == '#openModal') {
        location.hash = '';
    }
}

// Handle ESC key (key code 27)
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        modalClose();
    }
});

var modal = document.querySelector('#openModal');

// Handle click on the modal container
modal.addEventListener('click', modalClose, false);

// Prevent event bubbling if click occurred within modal content body
modal.children[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GG9Sa/264/

Note, that closing modal is technically possible with CSS/HTML only, however for handling Escape key press you will need Javascript.

Comment: Thanks dfsq. Strange though- when I do it in JFiddle, it works with both the click and escape, but when I put it into my page, only the escape works, not the click. I can live with only the escape key working, but it bumps me to the top of the page every time I hit it. How can I stop that? Thanks again, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Make sure you attach event handler to `#openModal` when it's already in DOM. For example execute this javascript before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have said I'm really a coding novice! LOL! I don't know what that means. I've put the script in the head of my document.

Comment: Exactly, this is a problem. If you put the script in the `head` DOM is not yet available (not loaded and not rendered yet). Put `<script>` tag before closing `</body>` tag. At this moment you make sure DOM is already there and you can bind events properly.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That works. The only issue is it still goes to the top of the page (#) when I either click out, or hit escape. Is there any way to make it stay where it is like when the X button is clicked? I tried putting #close where it says "modalClose();" (so it was modalClose(#close);

but that didn't work at all.

thanks again for all your help, it really is appreciated!!

Comment: Hi. I was able get the page portion sorted out by editing 'location.hash = '';' If you're able to put a proper link there instead of empty, it stops going to the top of the page.

Comment: And is there an elegant way to do this for any modal window if there are multiple of them, each with a unique ID, on a single webpage? Thanks in advance to anyone who can solve this.

Comment: keyCode is deprecated. It's better to do evt.key == 'Escape'

Answer (score 3):

just write these lines in your head tag

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
    location.href="#close";
  }   
});
```