# Close modal when click outside - multiple ID s

Tags: html, css

I use this [Modal](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) for multiple links on one page of my website. What I need is a script / code that closes the modal window when user clicks outside. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758991/css-html-modal-using-the-escape-key-click-outside-to-close), which works, but only for one link, since the script requires id. Is there a way to apply this script for multiple ID's? Or other methods?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's no JavaScript here...

Comment: There is js in the mentioned post.

Comment: @Alin Check my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the `id`, as it works out of `:target`, so what you need to do is, give a common class and different IDs for different modals like this:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
  var windows = document.getElementsByClassName("window");

  var clearModal = function () {
    location.hash = '';
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    modals[i].addEventListener('click', clearModal, false);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
    windows[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
    }, false);
  }
  document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      location.hash = '';
      clearModal();
    }
  }, false);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal .window {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
}
.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-1" class="modal">
  <div class="window">Modal Window 1<br /><a href="#">Close</a></div>
</div>
<div id="modal-2" class="modal">
  <div class="window">Modal Window 2<br /><a href="#">Close</a></div>
</div>
<div id="modal-3" class="modal">
  <div class="window">Modal Window 3<br /><a href="#">Close</a></div>
</div>
<div id="modal-4" class="modal">
  <div class="window">Modal Window 4<br /><a href="#">Close</a></div>
</div>
<div id="modal-5" class="modal">
  <div class="window">Modal Window 5<br /><a href="#">Close</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#modal-1">Open Modal 1</a><br />
<a href="#modal-2">Open Modal 2</a><br />
<a href="#modal-3">Open Modal 3</a><br />
<a href="#modal-4">Open Modal 4</a><br />
<a href="#modal-5">Open Modal 5</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already implemented multiple modals on the same page and they work fine. I only try to close them when clicking outside the modal window. The script I found in the mentioned post works fine, but only for one modal, cause it requires an id. (I cannot comment yet on that post cause this is a new account).

Comment: @Alin Okay, why not try my solution if that doesn't work out for you? This is flexible right?

Comment: It doesn't work when you click outside, only the close link.

Comment: @Alin Why not use a JavaScript solution? You can actually do it, by using JavaScript. Can I add that in my solution?

Comment: Yes please. I use java script (like in the post I mentioned) but it works only for one modal.

Comment: @Alin Works? Please let me know...

Comment: Works great, thank you so much. Also, Is it possible to achieve this when pressing ESC button?

Comment: @Alin Added Esc key support. `:D` Enjoy. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly as I need it. Thank you Praveen. Just realized I need to start learning java script asap. :)

Comment: @Alin That's JavaScript. No space.

Comment: I have one more Issue, hope you can help. When closing the modal window, it jumps on top of the page. Is there a way to maintain the scroll position?

Comment: @Alin That shouldn't happen, technically... Not sure why it happens for you.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the script, only some css alterations to fit my needs.

Comment: @Alin I am checking...